# I cant find my armature

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I hid my armature, tabbed into a different mode, now i cant select my armature or enter pose mode on that specific character. I tried highlighting it in the top right area and selecting it there, then tried doing option H, it didnt work. Please help. I even tried selecting a different character and going into pose mode. This did not help reveal the hidden armature.

Comment: I assume 'option H' is Mac-speak for Alt-H? Try selecting All (A key) in the Outliner and then use Alt-H. It could also be that you hid it while Edit mode and are trying to show it in Object mode. If so, select another object, go into Edit mode and see if Alt-H works.

Comment: No luck, unfortunatley

Comment: Possibly you are in the local view. Hit `#` to change.

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot of your whole interface?